# Consul server fails to rejoin the cluster, leaves after few seconds

Tags: networking, consul

a short overview of my case:

Originally I had a simple running consul cluster with one server (server1) and several clients. Here is my server1.json configuration file:

```json
{
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "data_dir": "/opt/consul",
    "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
    "client_addr":"0.0.0.0",
    "bootstrap_expect": 3,
    "ui": true,
    "retry_join": ["provider=aws tag_key=Function tag_value=consul-server"],
    "encrypt":"WT2T9..."
}
```

NOTE: **bootstrap_expect** was originally = 1, and I changed to 3 when I added new servers.

For some testing purposes I want to add two more servers to the cluster.

So I configure and add the servers one by one. Everything works as expected and I can confirm that my cluster now has 3 servers with two new servers (server1 and server2) being followers.

Here is my server2.json configuration file:

The config file for server3 looks the same.

Now when my cluster is running, for testing purposes I stoped the service of the server1, which was the leader. As a result, new leader was elected.

`consul members` command shows:

```
Node            Address           Status   Type   Build  Protocol  DC   Segment
server2  xx.xx.x.xx1:8301  alive   server  1.9.3  2         dc1  <all>
server1  xx.xx.x.xx2:8301  left    server  1.8.3  2         dc1  <all>
server3  xx.xx.x.xx3:8301  alive   server  1.9.3  2         dc1  <all>
```

Looks good! Server1 has left.

Now I want to bring server1 back to my cluster.

So I restart the consul.service of the server1 and I expect that it will rejoin the cluster.

**And it joins it, but in several seconds it is failed and leaves the cluster.**

Here are some outputs:

The output of `onsul members`:

```
 consul.service - Consul server agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/consul.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-04 13:33:25 UTC; 3s ago
     Docs: https://www.consul.io/
  Process: 18632 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/consul agent -ui -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/ (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 18632 (code=exited, status=2)

Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*Raft).runFSM.func2(0xc0007ec400, 0x40, 0x40)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/fsm.go:113 +0x75
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*Raft).runFSM(0xc000302900)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/fsm.go:219 +0x42f
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*raftState).goFunc.func1(0xc000302900, 0xc00085e340)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/state.go:146 +0x55
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: created by github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*raftState).goFunc
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/state.go:144 +0x66
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx systemd[1]: consul.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx systemd[1]: consul.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The output of `journalctl -xe -u consul` shows me the following

```
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.267Z [INFO]  agent: discover-aws: Instance i-0ae416a280967e345 has private ip 10.10.1.555: cluster=LAN
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.268Z [INFO]  agent: discover-aws: Instance i-0e5394a632853e200 has private ip 10.10.1.777: cluster=LAN
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.268Z [INFO]  agent: discover-aws: Instance i-019966401267318b4 has private ip 10.10.1.222: cluster=LAN
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.268Z [INFO]  agent: Discovered servers: cluster=LAN cluster=LAN servers="10.10.1.555 10.10.1.777 10.10.1.222"
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.268Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=[10.10.1.555, 10.10.1.777, 10.10.1.222]
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.271Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-1-777 10.10.1.777
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.271Z [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-10-1-222 10.10.1.222
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.272Z [INFO]  agent.server: Adding LAN server: server="ip-10-10-1-777 (Addr: tcp/10.10.1.777:8300) (DC: dc1)"
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.272Z [INFO]  agent.server: Adding LAN server: server="ip-10-10-1-222 (Addr: tcp/10.10.1.41:8300) (DC: dc1)"
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.274Z [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joined: number_of_nodes=3
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.275Z [INFO]  agent: Join cluster completed. Synced with initial agents: cluster=LAN num_agents=3
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.278Z [WARN]  agent.server.raft: failed to get previous log: previous-index=93400 last-index=93262 error="log not found"
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.505Z [INFO]  agent: Synced node info
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:     2021-02-04T13:33:25.526Z [INFO]  agent: Deregistered check: check=vault:10.10.1.555:8200:vault-sealed-check
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: panic: failed to decode request: invalid config entry kind: service-intentions
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: goroutine 37 [running]:
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent/consul/fsm.(*FSM).applyConfigEntryOperation(0xc000923c80, 0xc0008b0421, 0x150, 0x150, 0x169ef, 0x0, 0x0)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /home/circleci/project/consul/agent/consul/fsm/commands_oss.go:453 +0xb27
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent/consul/fsm.New.func1(0xc0008b0421, 0x150, 0x150, 0x169ef, 0xc000538a50, 0xc000eb9380)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /home/circleci/project/consul/agent/consul/fsm/fsm.go:85 +0x56
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent/consul/fsm.(*FSM).Apply(0xc000923c80, 0xc0013702d0, 0x0, 0x0)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /home/circleci/project/consul/agent/consul/fsm/fsm.go:120 +0x24b
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/go-raftchunking.(*ChunkingFSM).Apply(0xc000984780, 0xc0013702d0, 0x53a3f80, 0xbfff1bc9745fc84c)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/go-raftchunking@v0.6.1/fsm.go:66 +0x5b
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*Raft).runFSM.func1(0xc000956fe0)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/fsm.go:90 +0x2c1
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*Raft).runFSM.func2(0xc0007ec400, 0x40, 0x40)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/fsm.go:113 +0x75
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*Raft).runFSM(0xc000302900)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/fsm.go:219 +0x42f
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*raftState).goFunc.func1(0xc000302900, 0xc00085e340)
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/state.go:146 +0x55
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]: created by github.com/hashicorp/raft.(*raftState).goFunc
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx consul[18632]:         /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/raft@v1.1.2/state.go:144 +0x66
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx systemd[1]: consul.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 04 13:33:25 ip-xx-xx-x-xxx systemd[1]: consul.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As you can see from the second output, the server1 is actually joining the cluster, but then smth happens and it leaves it.

```
panic: failed to decode request: invalid config entry kind: service-intentions
```

I tried to modify configuration file in different ways and restart the consul server1 --> without success.

Finally I emptied the consul data_dir and restarted the server1 anew --> without success.

Has anybody experienced something like this and can support here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look few lines above the provided "panic" line, you can see:

[WARN] agent.server.raft: failed to get previous log: previous-index=93400 last-index=93262 error="log not found".

It seems like there is a problem with logs replication. The current leader is not able to replicate the logs to the new follower.

While I guess there can be multiple reasons for this, one possible problem can be in the version of consul. As far as I see from your consul members command, the version of *server1* is older than version of your leader (whether it is server2 or server3).

```
Node            Address           Status   Type   Build  Protocol  DC   Segment
server2  xx.xx.x.xx1:8301  alive   server  1.9.3  2         dc1  <all>
server1  xx.xx.x.xx2:8301  left    server  1.8.3  2         dc1  <all>
server3  xx.xx.x.xx3:8301  alive   server  1.9.3  2         dc1  <all>
```

Try to delete the consul binary from the problematic node (in your case server1) and replace it with the new version. After that restart consul.